# Is there a way how to recreate a field for a Dynamics CRM entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Our particular situation is that we have a DateOnly field and would like to change it to DateTime field supporting also the time portion. The operation is not allowed in UI and it's also stated in the documentation. Hence, I excepted deleting the field and recreating it with the new setting would work.
However when I try to create the field with the same name the `Duplicate Field Name` error is thrown. I've read the column actually still exists behind in the DB.

Of course, I could create a field with a new name but it would require changing all related workflows and code customizations.

Is there a way how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Aron already answered your question, but let me try asking some questions to narrow dow your requirement. How many records do you have in system where date field contains data? Can you not export all those records with date filed in excel and delete your old date field. Create new field with same name and then migrate data from excel again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting and recreating an attribute with the same name but different type should work - of course with the caveat that you have to remove all dependencies before deleting the attribute and recreate them with the new attribute.

The Duplicate Field Name error seems to indicate that the field still exists - perhaps the entity needs to be published after deleting.

You may also find the [XrmToolbox](https://xrmtoolbox.com) tool [Attribute Manager](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/DLaB.Xrm.AttributeManager/) helpful.

It allows you to migrate an attribute and its data to a new attribute.

Comment: Hi @Aron, at first I didn't want to mark your response as accepted because it does not specifically answer my question. My question was about recreating the field. However, I checked the tool and it really DOES support recreating the field. In fact I tried also recreating the field manually and it worked! So I believe it was only some kind of CRM glitch with cached metadata or something. Could you please edit the answer in a way it states the Delete & create scenario is valid and Attribute manager can help with data migrations and resolve dependencies. Then I'll accept you answer. Thanks.